# sql populated with column 1 but post with column 2

Tags: php, sql

I have a selectmenu populated with values from sql table, column 1. But Column 2 has values that I want to use. Is that possible? I tried it this way

```
<? php
$query = $db->query("select distinct column1, column2 from table1");
<select name="column1" id="column1" value="">
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php
if($rowCount > 0){
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
    echo '<option   value="'.$row['column2'].'">'.$row['column1'].'</option>';
 }
 }else{
echo '<option value="">contents column 1 not available</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, You can! What is wrong with this?

Comment: I editted the code. The problem is that I have to select both columns, so that the selectmenu is populated with both columns. If I select 1 column it doesn't work.

Comment: You need column2 for post value and column1 to display in HTML, right?

Comment: yes, that's true.

Comment: Then when you select column1 (that is a text to display in select box), column2 (the real value to be submitted) will be submitted.

Comment: yes, exactly, that's true.

Comment: May I know, what is the HTML rendered?

Comment: so you are basically asking, "can I select only one column when I need two"?

Comment: you mean the rest of the webpage?

Comment: `<select name="column1" id="column1" value="">` remove value attribute from this tag first! And tell me, what do you get once submitting the form?

Comment: the same problem occurs. the selectmenu is populated by both columns.

Comment: what is the rendered HTML of select box? can you add that in question?

Comment: sorry i don't understand your question. before this code there is ofcourse the <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title> etc. But that's not what you mean I guess?

Comment: I am asking about HTML part of select box.. first, right click on the page of the browser then click on View Page Source. and do ctrl+f and search for `<select ` and copy that whole <select> with options and paste it in question!!!!!

Comment: The selectmenu is created by the code that I posted above. Please don't be upset, I'm doing my best.

Comment: Solved the problem: added after 'table1': group by column2

Comment: that's good!!!!